# Tkinter add stroke to text

Tags: python, tkinter, stroke

I can't figure out how to add stroke to text with the `create_text` method.

There is no `outline` option defined in the method itself, does anyone know a method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there's no built-in way to add stroke to text, but you can configure your own. This kind of works by just making a bold-weighted text and overlaying regular text on it:

```
def stroke_text(x, y, text, textcolor, strokecolor):
    # make stroke text
    canvas.create_text(x, y, text=text, font=('courier', 16, 'bold'), fill=strokecolor)
    # make regular text
    canvas.create_text(x, y, text=text, font=('courier', 16), fill=textcolor)

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, bg='black')
canvas.pack()
stroke_text(100, 50, 'hello', 'white', 'red')

mainloop()
```

Although this probably looks more like a dropshadow than stroke; there's probably a way to improve this.